# What is the difference between Table<R> and <TableLike> in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Can someone in a nutshell tell me the difference between these two objects and why one might be used over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nutshell, TL;DR version:

You should only ever reference `Table`. jOOQ's internals also use `TableLike`

#### Full explanation:

jOOQ's DSL is full of little marker interfaces that are there only because the Java language lacks support for union types. For instance, in SQL syntax, a `Table<?>` (as in `CREATE TABLE x ...`) and a `Select<?>` (as in `SELECT * FROM ...`) are the same thing, when you put that thing in the `FROM` clause.

In an "ideal" Java language, the `FROM` clause would be declared as such:

```
interface SelectFromStep {
    SelectWhereStep from(Table | Select tableReference);
}
```

Because that's not possible, and because overloading and generic type erasure is a great source of pain when (ab)using generics like jOOQ does, jOOQ has these marker interfaces. Like `TableLike`, which is the super type of both `Table` and `Select`.

It is thus important only as a method parameter type in the jOOQ DSL, not to you as a user.